Retrofit java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to
I faced a problem. Retrofit shows me  java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.122.3.25:7068.
I also added ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in manifest file. But problem was not solved.
How can I solve this problem? Thank for your helps in advance.

Have you used <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> this permission ?

Yes I have used

Check this link https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1792
